# Totalling values with the same order ID in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a large excel speadsheet with (amongst others) the following columns

```
orderId   price
222       50.00
222       52.60
223       44.00
223       60.00
224       20.00
225       40.00
```

Is there a way to display the orderId as a Unique row with the **sum** of **all** prices under that id? So this example would result in

```
orderId   price
222       102.60
223       104.00
224       20.00
225       40.00
```

I'm happy to create a macro to do the job if necessary (I have VB knowledge but haven't used it for years and I've never applied it to excel before)

Comment: Have you thought about using a pivot table?  As asked, that looks like the best way to do this, by far.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that at the moment. Though currently unsure how to apply it to my needs. I keeps summing up the ID's instead of summing the price where the ID is the same

Comment: I can only summerize the data numerically. I need the orderId column to be treated as a string (I tried converting it and that doesn't work)

Comment: Yes, it's possible with a formula. Take a look to http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Unique_dates_from_list_formula.xls, where unique list is created for dates. After compiling the list, use SUMIF. I am in hurry now, can answer questions in some hours maybe.

Comment: The formula needed is array formula: use Ctrl-Shift-Enter in formula window to insert it, otherwise the result is incorrect.

Comment: Nothing you say sounds like a reason not to use a pivot. Just put the orderid in a row field and the price in a data field. It's worth it to try a little more :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved via Pivot table unless i am mistaking your requirement.

Insert -> Pviot table

set as below

[image: pivot table]

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a VBA solution, you can just copy and paste the Order ID column and use "remove duplicates" from the Excel ribbon to make a unique list. Then to the right of each entry, just put =SUMIF(A:A, C1, B:B), where A:A I assume is the order ID column, C1 is the first entry in the unique list, and B:B i assume is where the values are.

=SUMIF(what is the range you want to look through?, what do you want to look for?, where are the values you want to add up?)

For VBA, you could get fancy and use the dictionary object, simply entering each unique value you find in the object id column, and if it exists, then just add the total to the value for that entry. At the end, just use the .keys and .items to output the list. :)